# Specifying that parameter is a database in the constructor

Tags: php

In the following code:

```
protected $db;

    public function __construct(Database $db) 
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
```

What is the point in specifying that the parameter $db is a Database if you can name it whatever you want and it will still work?

Comment: The naming of a variable / property has nothing to do with its type. What would happen if you passed in an object of type `Date`, for example? Errors would be thrown that methods / properties do not exist.

Comment: No I mean the `Database` keyword before the variable name. How do I search about this convention so I can learn more about it?

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. That specifies what *type* the variable `$db` should be. You're aware that variables in PHP can have different types, right?

Comment: Yes, int, bool, etc.. but Database?  I have seen it named just `db` and it still works.

Comment: Please see my answer, it should provide all you need to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a type declaration. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

> Type declarations allow functions to require that parameters are of a
>   certain type at call time. If the given value is of the incorrect
>   type, then an error is generated: in PHP 5, this will be a recoverable
>   fatal error, while PHP 7 will throw a
>   [TypeError](http://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php) exception.
>
> To specify a type declaration, the type name should be added before
>   the parameter name. The declaration can be made to accept `NULL`
>   values if the default value of the parameter is set to `NULL`.

So, if we didn't specify the type declaration for `$db` in your code, we could instantiate the class with a `null` argument, which would cause the object's `$db` parameter to be set to `null`:

```
$object = new ClassName( null );
```

By specifying that the single parameter for the constructor **must** be of type `Database`, PHP will throw an error (or exception in PHP 7) if we pass it anything other than a `Database` object. For example:

```
$object = new ClassName( null ); // Throws an error / exception

$db     = new Database();
$object = new ClassName( $db ); // Performs as expected.
```

In this particular case, `Database` is an object type defined by the framework/library you're working with (i.e. `class Database { ... }`).

Comment: I see now. Thank you for the examples, they really helped me!